# ios - Module field empty while custom class is present

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, xcode10, carthage

The custom module on my Identity inspector is empty, though the classes are there. This is causes an "Unknown class error".
I'm using Carthage. Please help

**UPDATE**
I just had to press enter but now they designables doesn't show on the utilities panel

Comment: Check the class's Target Membership

Comment: @Woodstock The class target membership is that of my project.